# How do I solve for A in the matrix equation $A - B(A./C) = D$?

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-equations

I've got $A - B(A./C) = D$, and I want to solve for $A$.*

$A$ is an unknown 2x1 vector, $B$ is a known 2x2 matrix, $C$ is a known 2x1 vector, and $D$ is a known 2x1 vector.

*The notation $A./C$ means each element of A is being divided by an element that has the same index in $C$. So, if $A$ = \begin{bmatrix}1\\3\end{bmatrix} and $C$ = \begin{bmatrix}2\\3\end{bmatrix} then $A./C$ =  \begin{bmatrix}0.5\\1\end{bmatrix}.

Comment: Set $M_{ij}=\frac{1}{C_{ij}}$. Under your definition, $A/C=AM=MA$. $/$ only makes sense when entries are all nonzero

Comment: Does it help if you rewrite $A./C$ as a product $C'A$, where $C'$ is a known diagonal matrix?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that works great since I am working with a vector.

Answer (score 1):

If $C$ is known, then a diagonal matrix $C'$ can be created with its $i$th diagonal element equals to the reciprocal of the $i$th element in vector $C$. Then $A./C = C'A$.

The matrix equation can then be factorised and then solved:
$$\begin{align*}
A - B(A./C) &= D\\
IA-BC'A &= D\\
(I-BC')A &= D
\end{align*}$$

Comment: *facepalm* Thanks! That works great!